# Selenium Python | Explicit Waits - Properly Using

Tags: python, selenium

I was watching YouTube video where I'd noticed that the following code:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="...") # here just creates new Chrome driver

try:
   driver.get(URI)
   time.sleep(3)
   
   respond = driver.page_source
   print(respond)

except Exception as _ex:
   print(_ex)
finally:
   driver.close()
   driver.quit()
```

But at the same time it says that you don't have to use `time.sleep` statement. Instead you can use WebDriverWait.

So my question is how could we refactor this code using WebDriverWait and why do we need to use wait here in general?

Comment: Actually, I think using webdriver wait lets your code continues its processing during the waiting but when you use time.sleep() its like you make a space between two clocks of cpu.

Comment: Check this question/answer(s):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable

Comment: You don't need to use a wait or sleep after a .get().  Selenium will automatically wait for the page to load.  The only exception to this would be a "lazy-load" style site where placeholders are populated after the page loads or if you've changed pageloadstrategy.  A webdriverwait is more efficient than a sleep because it will only wait as long as needed for the explicit condition to be met.